# How do you breed a Blue Moon Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I just got an app notification that a Blue Moon dragon is available for breeding. Now I must know how to breed it! What is the best combination of dragons?

Comment: Better find it quick! It's apparently only available til Monday!

Comment: An anonymous user posted this as an edit to the question: "I got one with a scorch and storm".

Comment: Naturally that sounds like an answer rather than a question edit.  I'm sure they were just trying to help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that this is a ultra rare dragon and you will need some **random** luck to get it.

**Cold Dragon** + **Lightning Dragon** Is one confirmed combination,however using any lightning and cold elements should suffice.*Any dragon + Storm Dragon* is another rumor.

[more info](http://www.gameteep.net/dragonvale/blue-moon-dragon/)

Comment: Looking on the wikia, it says It's bred exactly the same as the Moon dragon, so cold and lightning are *required*. Any other elements will just reduce your chance, I'd think. It also has a breed time of 29 hours and 31 minutes.

Comment: I tried many times with straight Lightning and Cold with no luck. Eventually I switched to Storm + Lightning and Storm + Plant and got my pair. Whoo hoo!

Comment: @Arremer I have since researched and found that the statistically fastest combos are (Firefly OR Scorch) + Storm.  Statistically you'll have success ~10 hours faster (on average) with continuous breeding.

Answer (score 2):

I got one with a cold dragon and a lightning dragon on my first try

Answer (score 1):

On my first try I got one with fire and storm, and on my second try I got one with sonic and iceberg.